# Generating two ssl certificates for the same host

Tags: ssl, certificate

I have a a situation where the host has a SSL certificate with incorrect CN name configured. Worse still many clients connect to this service. Now there is a requirement to change the CN name in the certificate.

Here is what I am considering. Please let me know if i am missing something:

1. generate another certificate for the new CN, import it to JKS[Java Key Store]. By having two certificates the idea is to let clients move to the new certificates seamlessly at their own pace. once all clients migrate we remove the old certificate from the keystore. I tried doing this approach. however, when I access the service with the new CN, I get the " **hostname in certificate didn't match**" error. I can still access the old CN.
2. another approach i was thinking of having a multi-domain certificate. in this approach I will generate a new certificate with SAN name for the old CN with CN being the new name. i am hoping this will allow the clients to work with the service using both CN names. However, after this option is only feasible if the SAN referring to old CN can be deleted when all clients start using the new CN.

Comment: *now there is a requirement to change the CN name in the certificate.*. you do not do that. you just generate a new certificate (as in: ask the relevant certificate authority to provide you with a new certificate), and you change your  configuration to use the new one. Or you can have a single certificate with both names as SANs. Or even a wildcard one. All of this work technically with same results. So your error "hostname in certificate didn't match" just means a local configuration error and you give no specific live data for anyone to help you. Also it is not a programming related question

Comment: A JKS can have only one cert chain per PrivateKeyEntry; if you `-importcert` a new chain to an existing PrivateKeyEntry (alias) that it matches, it replaces the prior one, and if you import a cert to a different alias it becomes a TrustedCertEntry and not usable for SSL/TLS server. Whether multiple PrivateKeyEntry&cert's can be used correctly or at all depends on the server software, often its version and the Java version, all of which you have omitted. If you use SAN (which is the modern way) then clients _must ignore_ Subject.CN so you need both/all names in SAN.

Comment: The java version is 1.8. and both these certs in question are signed by the same CA.

Comment: I went with SAN approach. post that I am able to refer two CNAMES with the same certifcate.

Comment: I had a follow up question on this. if set a cookie in the application, for which domain would the cookie be set?